# Add spacing to textbox results

Tags: c#, textbox, spacing

Hi there I have the following code-

```
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + action + "ok: " + ok.ToString();
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "err: " + err.ToString();
        richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\r\n";
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
```

The results look like -

ok:7err:0

But I want-

ok:7

err:0

With spacing, to make it look better how can I do this?

Comment: add one more `"\r\n"` at the end of ok statement..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add another 2 lines:

```
richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
richTextBox1.Text += Environment.NewLine;
```

between your "ok" and "err" - assuming you want a blank line between the two lines of output. However, you should either be using `string.Format` or a `StringBuilder` to create your output as concatenating strings this way in inefficient.

You also don't need the final:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;
```

as that is just setting the text box contents back to itself and does nothing.

Comment: Or use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got your answer, you just have it in the wrong place! The key is to use the escape sequence `\r\n`, which inserts a carriage return and a new line.

Also, there's no reason to split this code up into multiple lines. You end up incurring a performance penalty for doing so. It's better to do all of the string concatenation at one time. (You aren't doing enough concatenations here to justify using the `StringBuilder` class, but it's worth keeping in mind that strings are immutable in .NET and writing code accordingly.)

Try rewriting the code like this:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + action + "ok: " + ok.ToString(); + "\r\n" +
                "err: " + err.ToString(); + "\r\n";
```

You can also complete eliminate the last line of code, as that simply sets the value of `textBox1.Text` to itself. It's a no-op, meaning that it does nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

first that you could do all these in a single statement, second you could use += operator instead, and third what is that last statement doing?! it not needed, fourth add "\n" after each part you need there is no limit where you should put it, no "\r" needed.

Comment: Using the `+=` operator here doesn't get you anywhere special. It's just syntactic sugar for the code he already has. It neither fixes the original problem, nor the inefficiency arising from the way the string concatenations are performed.

Comment: @Code Gray, Yes but it's understood better, I'd rather seeing a += operator instead of looking for: a = junk + a + junk;

Comment: Looks the same to me. The important thing is that you understand what the code is doing, rather than looking for easily-recognized patterns in the syntax. They mean exactly the same thing, that should be obvious upon inspection.